# Truncate list of breadcrumbs - and keep the markup

Tags: jquery, truncation

I have this script which truncates long lists which is really useful for long breadcrumbs. However, the result is rendered as a list of `a`tags only.

How can the script be changed to output `li` list items - like the original markup?

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
  <li>You are here: </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Long item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Long item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Really long item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Really, really long item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Long item</a></li>
  <li class="active">Active page</li>
</ul>
```

Script:

```
 /* Truncate breadcrumbs when over a certain number of levels, and remove link from current page.
     *
     * Options:
     *      intro           {String}    Introductory text, may include markup
     *      separator       {String}    Separating character(s)
     *      maxLevels       {Number}    Integer of maximum levels to show without truncation
     *      startCrumbs     {Number}    Integer of levels to show before the truncated levels
     *      endCrumbs       {Number}    Integer of levels to show after the truncated levels
     *      crumbMaxLength  {Number}    Maximum character length for breadcrumb titles to show without truncation
     */

    $.fn.breadcrumbs = function(options) {
      var el = $(this);

      // truncate individual titles if over set length
      $('a', el).each(function() {
        var crumbTitle = $(this).text();
        if (crumbTitle.length > options.crumbMaxLength) {
          $(this).text(
            $.trim(crumbTitle).substring(0, 40).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "…"
          );
        }
      });

      // remove the link from the current page crumb
      $('.active', el).replaceWith(
        $('<span/>').text($('.active', el).text())
      );

      var crumbs = $.map($('a, span', el).toArray(), function(x) {
        return x.outerHTML;
      });

      // if truncation needed
      if (crumbs.length > options.maxLevels) {
        var firstCrumbs = crumbs.slice(0, options.startCrumbs);
        var hideCrumbs = '<a href="#" title="Show all">…</a>';
        var lastCrumbs = crumbs.slice(crumbs.length - options.endCrumbs);
        var newCrumbs = firstCrumbs.concat([hideCrumbs]).concat(lastCrumbs);
        el.html(options.intro + newCrumbs.join(options.separator));
      } else {
        el.html(options.intro + crumbs.join(options.separator));
      }

      // show the hidden breadcrumbs when ellipsis is clicked
      $('[title]', el).click(function() {
        el.html(options.intro + crumbs.join(options.separator));
      });
    };

    // breadcrumb truncation settings
    $('.breadcrumbs').breadcrumbs({
      intro: '<li>Your are here: </li>',
      separator: ' > ',
      maxLevels: 5,
      startCrumbs: 1,
      endCrumbs: 2,
      crumbMaxLength: 40
    });
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/noh78j2p/3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your breadcrumb function to have another option called `wrapWithLi`. If passed in option and is true, it will wrap your breadcrumb with li otherwise with a.

```
/* Truncate breadcrumbs when over a certain number of levels, and remove link from current page.
     *
     * Options:
     *      intro           {String}    Introductory text, may include markup
     *      separator       {String}    Separating character(s)
     *      maxLevels       {Number}    Integer of maximum levels to show without truncation
     *      startCrumbs     {Number}    Integer of levels to show before the truncated levels
     *      wrapWithLi      {boolean}    wrap element with li. if false or not passed defaults to 'a'
     *      endCrumbs       {Number}    Integer of levels to show after the truncated levels
     *      crumbMaxLength  {Number}    Maximum character length for breadcrumb titles to show without truncation
     */

$.fn.breadcrumbs = function(options) {
  var el = $(this);

  var wrap = options.wrapWithLi === true ? 'li' : 'a';

  // truncate individual titles if over set length
  $(wrap, el).each(function() {
    var crumbTitle = $(this).text();
    if (crumbTitle.length > options.crumbMaxLength) {
      $(this).text(
        $.trim(crumbTitle).substring(0, 40).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "…"
      );
    }
  });

  // remove the link from the current page crumb
  $('.active', el).replaceWith(
    $('<span/>').text($('.active', el).text())
  );

  var crumbs = $.map($(wrap + ', span', el).toArray(), function(x) {
    return x.outerHTML;
  });

  // if truncation needed
  if (crumbs.length > options.maxLevels) {
    var firstCrumbs = crumbs.slice(0, options.startCrumbs);
    var hideCrumbs = '<a href="#" title="Show all">…</a>';

    if (wrap === 'li') {
        hideCrumbs = '<li>'+ hideCrumbs +'</li>';
    }

    var lastCrumbs = crumbs.slice(crumbs.length - options.endCrumbs);
    var newCrumbs = firstCrumbs.concat([hideCrumbs]).concat(lastCrumbs);
    el.html(options.intro + newCrumbs.join(options.separator));
  } else {
    el.html(options.intro + crumbs.join(options.separator));
  }

  // show the hidden breadcrumbs when ellipsis is clicked
  $('[title]', el).click(function() {
    el.html(options.intro + crumbs.join(options.separator));
  });
};

// breadcrumb truncation settings
$('.breadcrumbs').breadcrumbs({
  intro: '<li>Your are here: </li>',
  separator: ' > ',
  maxLevels: 5,
  startCrumbs: 1,
  wrapWithLi: true,
  endCrumbs: 2,
  crumbMaxLength: 40
});
```

Here is working  **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7tbtzco/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution is as simple as replacing

```
return x.outerHTML;
```

with

```
return "<li>"+ x.outerHTML + "</li>";
```